# SQL Query for a possible self join?

Tags: sql, self-join, presto

I have a row with two i.d fields I.D_a,  I.D_b, and a status field. Only the status for I.D_a exists in the row.  I.D_b is I.D_a in another row where I.D_b is null. So I.D_b is I.D_a in another row whos I.D_b is null.

How can I pull the status of I.D_b when its status is in a different row where the value of I.D_b = I.D_a ?

Comment: What exactly is the input & output? [mcve] PS And when you *tried* a self cross join with simple data, which were the rows you wanted to keep?

Comment: Im sorry not familiar with how to upload the input and output?

I only want to keep rows that have i.d_a that exist in that table as an i.d_b if that makes sense? @philipxy

Comment: Please clarify via post edit, not comments. The output here would maybe be a table value for your base & 1 for your query result. You would set the table via an update statement & give the query result text. What I meant re trying was, please don't ask a question until you have tried reasonalby to answer it, and please show what parts you can do, and if you experimented with a little example you should have learned a lot, including about your JOIN's ON. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover text. And a code question should have a [mcve] with clear specification & cut & paste & runnable code.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select ta.*, tb.status as b_status
from t ta left join
     t tb
     on ta.id_b = tb.id_a and tb.id_b is null;
```

Comment: Inner join not outer join. Although the input constraints & desired results are not clear.